# define WIN32 inside X64 project

Tags: c++, winapi

I am developing X64 C++ project using MSVS 2015. I want to link a library that I pulled and compiled myself using the same version and configuration(X64).

This library uses something like inside its headers:

```
#ifndef WIN32
#include <sys/time.h>
#endif
```

And yes as you guessed, it does not compile since there is no `<sys/time.h>` in Windows and in the same time the `WIN32` is not defined since I am on X64.

Is it safe to define `WIN32` by myself inside X64 project?

**Note**: I tried it and it is working. I am just afraid of future problems (if any).

Comment: If it's any indication, Visual Studio 2015 defines `_WIN32` for 32-bit ARM, 64-bit ARM, x86 and x64. [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx). Can't say for sure, it depends on the libraries you use, and rather or not you use that particular macro yourself. Try it out and see?

Comment: It seems like a good indication.. thanks

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I tried and it is working well. I am just afraid that it may causes me a future problems

Comment: The short answer is yes, you can `#define WIN32` safely.

Comment: Note that Win32 is the name of the API, as distinct from the now obsolete Win16 API.  Both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows programs use the Win32 API, so the fact that your program is 64-bit isn't relevant.  There is no Win64 API.

Comment: Arguably, that's a bug in the library. It should use `_WIN32` in the preprocessor conditional, because that controls the language implementation. `WIN32` is just a 'random' symbol used by the Windows SDK, not the compiler or language implementation.